# Having Issues with XbarCode Reports of DevExpress in Dot Net C#

Tags: .net, devexpress, barcode, xtrareport

I am creating the XBarCode report on Label 4x2 , Printing through Zebra Printer. I am using code to create the barcode setting properties, Barcode Generated Successfully but unable to scan it. It is scannable when i increase the width and print on A4 size page but not scannable on 4x2 (inches) label on zebra printer. Any Help will be appreciated!

```
        this.barcodeSerial.Alignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.barcodeSerial.AnchorHorizontal = DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.HorizontalAnchorStyles.Left;
        this.barcodeSerial.AutoModule = true;
        this.barcodeSerial.BarCodeOrientation = 
        DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BarCode.BarCodeOrientation.RotateLeft;
        this.barcodeSerial.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None;
        this.barcodeSerial.Dpi = 100F;
        this.barcodeSerial.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 4F, 
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.barcodeSerial.LocationFloat = new DevExpress.Utils.PointFloat(162F, 7.494577F);
        this.barcodeSerial.Module = 0.5F;
        this.barcodeSerial.Name = "barcodeSerial";
        this.barcodeSerial.Padding = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PaddingInfo(0, 0, 0, 0, 100F);
        this.barcodeSerial.ShowText = false;
        this.barcodeSerial.SizeF = new System.Drawing.SizeF(19F, 180.3369F);
        this.barcodeSerial.StylePriority.UseBorders = false;
        this.barcodeSerial.StylePriority.UseFont = false;
        this.barcodeSerial.StylePriority.UsePadding = false;
        this.barcodeSerial.StylePriority.UseTextAlignment = false;
        code128Generator1.CharacterSet = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BarCode.Code128Charset.CharsetAuto;
        this.barcodeSerial.Symbology = code128Generator1;
        this.barcodeSerial.Text = "LGLS9988BDD34E3L";
        this.barcodeSerial.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks
Some Screenshots of barcode and changed automodule to false as well.
[image: Barcode Image]

[image: Properties]

Comment: you may try to remove "automodule=true" and manually experiment with mudule value - for normal scanning it should be 1.0 or greater, also try to print with greater dpi on  your printer

Comment: @k0st1x i have tried that as well, but no gain :(

Comment: what exactly you've tried? what the result on preview? can you share a sample problematic report layout?

Comment: @k0st1x if i increase the module to 1 or greater than 1 , error comes up of width issue.

Comment: so you should to increase the control boundaries. also check the printer dpi, preferred value is 300 or greater dpi.

Comment: @k0st1x if i increase the control boundaries.,, its not fitting in 4x2 label barcode.

Comment: i see. you really can use the fractional number for the module which is lower that "1". but firstly you should known the zebra's dpi and calculates how you report's dpi will be converted to the printers dpi so barcode control has no "dense" and report's dots will be frieldly for the printer dots. for more details review the devexpress article https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/118336/Barcode-Generation-API/Concepts/Bar-Code-Recognition-Specifics#common-issues

Comment: @k0st1x hi thanks.
203 dpi print resolution (8 dots/mm) of zebra printer. and my label is 4x2 (inches) The Characters i want to print on label are "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST" (20 Characters Length)
Can you help me what should be the properties to set for XtraReport?

Comment: 100/203=0.49261083743842365 (minimum), you can try 0.9852216748768473 (x2) if it will fit into bounds. also you can try to change the zebra printer dpi (300 or 600) to try diferent control sizes.

Comment: @k0st1x Thanks
but that does not work for me as well.